# Global in NodeJS application

Tags: node.js, global

I am working on a NodeJS application, I have different modules and in those modules different packages as those packages are using functions from other packages, I had a problem requiring controllers everywhere so what i did is, I Globalized those controllers,

e.g.

```
global.CTRLS = { userCtrl : [require('./User/profile/controller/profileCtrl')]    
, productCtrl : [require('./Product/Products/controller/productCtrl')] }
```

so my question is

1. Is there any performance issue while globalizing these controllers, will there be any performance effect on my application?
2. If there is an issue using global what can be the other better way?

Comment: Globalizing modules is not a good idea, because it can mess up your variables. have a look [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2169-where-does-node-js-and-require-look-for-modules.htm) for some basic introduction. please, show some code if we should help you practical on your issues

Comment: I am globalizing just the controllers which are containing  functions inside those modules, can you tell me a better way?

Comment: can you show your code, please?

Comment: What do you mean by "globalizing?". Are you aware of the `global` variable?

Comment: I have multy controllers and those controllers are being used inside each others so instead of requiring them every where i created a `global.CTRLS` whcih contain all the controller functions

Comment: code ===>                 ` global.CTRLS = {
   userCtrl : [require('./User/profile/controller/profileCtrl')]
   , productCtrl : [require('./Product/Products/controller/productCtrl')]

};`

Comment: thx. it would be better to update your question, so you can format your code to something readable, btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a mix of requires (as in @Hinrich answer) and `global.someNamespaceName.anInstance`.

In general, I use the `global.someNamespaceName.anInstance` to refer to an *object*, i.e. a specific instantiation of the class, such as a specific database connection, or the specific configuration of your application.  For example, in the main application initialization code, something like

```
var config = { lots of config stuff, e.g.  .mongoURI, .port, .loggerFormat, .prefs, ... }
...
global.myAppName.config = config ;
global.myAppName.myMongo = new MyMongo(config.mongoURI);
global.myAppName.mySQL = new MySQL(config.mySQLSettings);
```

I use **requires** mainly for the "typical" node-ish things and standard libraries, i.e. `var QueryString = require('querystring');`

This "seems right" to my thinking, but don't know if there are any specific guidelines, and either way is fine.  The advantage of global.xxx is that you can  avoid having dozens of requires at the start of every file, and ordering can be an issue.

Two possible drawbacks of using global.myAppName.someOtherName:

1. Namespace collision.  Shouldn't be a problem unless you have a huge project and multiple programmers who don't communicate.  And this is something that could happen with requires too...
2. It takes two lookups (.myAppName and .someOtherName) to find the object, which will be an **extremely minor** performance hit.  If you are referring to the item thousands of times in a loop, cache it in a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

you can `require` your controllers in the modules where you need them. so inside a module, e.g.

```
var profileCtrl = require('./User/profile/controller/profileCtrl');
```

or wherever your controller lives, relative to your calling module. Then you have access to your controller and you can access it's exported variables and functions.